# Squaring a Procedure in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, procedure

I am an electrical engineer who is trying to learn scheme in internet.I want to take the square of sin x but i fail.I think I need a function which makes (Number,Number) - (Number,Number).So it should take lambda x and lambda f and calculate square (f x).But I am stuck and I cant write this code. Can anyone write this?

Answer (score 5):

Just nest the function calls. An easy way would be:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(square (sin x))
```

Or create a composed function:

```
(define square-sin (compose square sin))

(square-sin x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas here:

```
(define (sqr-f f) (compose sqr f))
```

Usage:

```
((sqr-f sin) 1)
```

Or an uncurried version:

```
(define (sqr-f-u f . x) (sqr (apply f x)))
```

Usage:

```
(sqr-f-u + 1 2)
```